# List not updating correctly?

Tags: java, list

Ive been following TheCherno's network chat programming tutorials, and I am almost done, just fixing bugs when I ran into a problem. I have a button that opens a window that is supposed to have a list of all the connected users listed. However, everytime I test it, the only item on the list is the first person who connected to that instance of the server. It is the same for all of the other users connected as well. I have no errors in my code, and it all seems correct. I can't seem to find the error.

This function is called from a while running loop, and everything else in it is working constantly, so I don't think there is something wrong in this.

```
private void sendStatus() {
        if (clients.size() <= 0) return;
    String users = "/u/";
    for (int i = 0; i < clients.size() - 1; i++) {
        users += clients.get(i).name + "/n/";
    }
    users += clients.get(clients.size() - 1).name + "/e/";
    sendToAll(users);
}
```

This is from another class, where the client decodes the messages sent from the server.

```
else if (message.startsWith("/u/")) {
                    String[] u = message.split("/u/|/n/|/e/");
                    users.update(Arrays.copyOfRange(u, 1, u.length - 1));
                }
```

And then this is the peice that handles the graphics of it, I don't see anything wrong in it, but I will include it anyway jsut in case. Thanks all!

```
    private JPanel contentPane;
private JList list;
public OnlineUsers() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(200, 320);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    GridBagLayout gbl_contentPane = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl_contentPane.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0};
    gbl_contentPane.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0};
    gbl_contentPane.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    gbl_contentPane.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    contentPane.setLayout(gbl_contentPane);

    list = new JList();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_list = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_list.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_list.gridx = 0;
    gbc_list.gridy = 0;
    JScrollPane p = new JScrollPane();
    p.setViewportView(list);
    contentPane.add(p, gbc_list);
    list.setFont(new Font("Verdana", 0, 14));
}

public void update(String[] users) {
    list.setListData(users);
}
```

Still no ideas at all. I even checked the source code that the tutorial person made and its the same thing. I would really appreciate the help, as I am 14 and just learning java. Bump.
https://github.com/TheCherno/ChernoChat

Comment: can you give a testcase that fails...

Comment: My advice is to put a println (or breakpoint if you know how to use a debugger in your IDE) after `String[] u = message.split("/u/|/n/|/e/")` and check if `u` array really contains what you would expect. It will be easier for you to debug the app than for the people here :-)

Comment: I tried that and it gave me something strange like [L Java.Lang.String @7e37843 or something like that. That doesnt help me at all.

Comment: @jmaster2013 You can use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(u));` to get the actual values instead of Java default toString for arrays which prints the object reference.

Comment: @PawełChorążyk I did that and it is still only the first person. So I know its an error before it makes the list, correct? The problem is I also got the count of how many clients there were in clients array and that is correct, and I added a console command to see the clients and there are the right amount with the right number.

Comment: @jmaster2013 With how many clients are you testing it? Well you know that probably what you receive in the other class is already incorrect.

Comment: @PawełChorążyk I had 3 open. I have done it with 2. It works for cherno in the tutorial with 2. I have the same code.